# DataGridView filtered

Tags: vb.net, foreach, datagridview

I have to highlight the datagridview rows at runtime if the checkbox of the first column is flagged. I can't use a normal
`for each`
loop to color the rows because there are about 3000 of them and it would take too long.

I should directly filter the rows from the `for each` loop with the condition **Column1 = True** ...
... could you help me find the right synopsis: I tried with:

```
For Each selRows As DataGridViewRow In myDataGrid.SelectedColumns(0).Equals("Column1 = true")
  myDataGrid.Rows(selRows.index).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
Next
```

but it does not work

Thank you

Comment: `SelectedColumns` is a collection of `DataGridViewColumns`, so the first item in that collection is a `DataGridViewColumn`. How to could that ever be equal to a `String`? What you actually want is rows where the `Value` of the first cell is `True`. Of course, there are better ways to do the whole thing but, using your logic, that's what you should be doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CellPainting event

```
Private Sub dgv_CellPainting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles dgv.CellPainting
   '   check if the row is the header row
   If e.RowIndex = -1 Then
       Exit Sub
   End If
   '   cast the row to the correct data type, here I'll assume this is a datarow
   Dim row As DataRow = CType(dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem, DataRowView).Row
   '   perform your check 
   If CType(row("Column1"), Boolean) Then
       dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
   End If
End Sub
```